# combination of two jquery codes in a file not workins as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my html code

```
<div class="wrapper"> <strong> Number of images:</strong>
<div class="formText">
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="100" />100
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="200" />200
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="300" />300
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="other" />other
</div>
</div>

<div  class="wrapper"> <strong><span>*</span> Image to be displayed:</strong>
                <div class="formText">
                <input type="radio" name="rdImage" value="uploadImage" /> Upload your own image
                <input style="margin-left:10px;" type="file" name="user_upload_image" class="uploader" id="file">
                <br />
                <input type="radio" name="rdImage" value="preExisting"/> Choose from images below
                <div class="100 imgDisp">
                    <div class="heading">
                        10x10 = 100
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="200 imgDisp">
                    <div class="heading">
                        10x20 = 200
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="200 imgDisp">
                    <div class="heading">
                        20x10 = 200
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="300 imgDisp">
                    <div class="heading">
                        10x30 = 300
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="300 imgDisp">
                    <div class="heading">
                        30x10 = 300
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

this is jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("div.imgDisp").hide();
$('.' + $(":radio:checked").val()).show();
    $('input[name="rdNumber"]:radio').click(function() {
     $("div.imgDisp").fadeOut('slow');
    $('.' + $(this).val()).fadeIn('slow');
});
});

var rdImage = $('input:radio[name="rdImage"]');
var rdNumbers= $('input:radio[name="rdNumber"]');
rdNumbers.change(function(e){
var $target = $(e.target);
if($target.is(':checked')){
    if($target.is('[value="other"]')){
        rdImage.not('[value="uploadImage"]').prop('disabled', true);
        rdNumberPages.filter('[value="uploadImage"]').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        rdNumberPages.not('[value="uploadImage"]').prop('disabled', false);
    }
}
});
```

the purpose of jquery code is 
1. to display "10x10 = 100", "10x20 = 200", "20x10 = 200" etc.. (whatever is appropriate) on selection of "100", "200", "300" (i.e. rdNumber radio) matching the values.. till now it is working fine

1. now I tried to add the functionality of disabling and re-enabling "Choose from images below" radio on selection of "other" radio. I got success in disabling.. i.e. when I select "other" radio it is disabling "Choose from images below" radio but on selecting 300, 200 or 100 it is not enabling it again.. Help needed in this case..
2. Also how can it be done that when user select "other" it disables "Choose from images below" and when user select 100,  200, 300 radio it enables "Choose from images below", but it shall auto-select "Choose from images below" radio button and that shall display the hidden div as per 1 above. i.e. if user select 100 it shall automatically select "Choose from images below" and shall display the applicable div i.e. "10x10 = 100" this I m not able to accomplish.. however there shall be no restriction on manual user selection of "Upload your own image" radio or "Choose from images below"

here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/xeMjC/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of issues that stood out straight away. Firstly, you were missing the `});` at the bottom of the java script (that is opened at the top of the page).

Secondly, the variable 'rdNumberPages' is never declared anywhere, which makes some of the code not work.

I have made some small changes to the code, which you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xeMjC/3/)

Comment: y is these lines repeated??

Comment: ... because I was leaving the work of refactoring the code to be in the style of the developer up to you ;) In case you are worrying about some extra bytes being used, here is a fixed version. http://jsfiddle.net/xeMjC/5/

Comment: can u do a little modification also?? on clicking "Upload your own image" radio "10x10 = 100", "20x10 = 200" etc... divs shall be hidden and on selecting "Choose from images below" they shall be visible again taking into account selection from here "Number of images:" i.e. 100, or 200 or 300??

Comment: You can do it. It is a matter of changing the code just a little that is already there! Move all of the code that is inside the .click  function into a new function, and call that function instead.

Then you can do a check just before fadeIn() to see if you should actually show the div or not.

**I have faith in you** :)